# Customizing achart engine XYMultipleSeriesRenderer display

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am currently working on an android application where I need to display linegraph. I choose achartengine and make XYMultipleSeriesRenderer  with timeseries. I am using following code.

```
private void openChart(){       

    int count = 5;
    Date[] dt = new Date[5];
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, i+1);
        dt[i] = gc.getTime();
    }

    int[] visits = { 40,40,40,40,40};
    int[] views = {55, 51, 44, 41, 39};     

    // Creating TimeSeries for Visits
    TimeSeries visitsSeries = new TimeSeries("Theshold");       

    // Creating TimeSeries for Views
    TimeSeries viewsSeries = new TimeSeries("Readings");        

    // Adding data to Visits and Views Series
    for(int i=0;i<dt.length;i++){
        visitsSeries.add(dt[i], visits[i]);
        viewsSeries.add(dt[i],views[i]);
    }

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);

    // Adding Visits Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(viewsSeries);     


    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries      
    XYSeriesRenderer thresholdRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    thresholdRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    thresholdRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    thresholdRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    thresholdRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    thresholdRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize viewsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer readingRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    readingRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    readingRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    readingRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    readingRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    readingRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(5);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(90);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(-20);
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Time Stamps");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Temperature");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);      

    // Adding visitsRenderer and viewsRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(thresholdRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(readingRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

    // Creating a Time Chart
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer,"dd-MMM-yyyy");         

    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (seriesSelection != null) {                  
                int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                String selectedSeries="Visits";
                if(seriesIndex==0)
                    selectedSeries = "Visits";
                else
                    selectedSeries = "Views";

                // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection.getXValue();
                Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                // Getting the y value 
                int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                // Displaying Toast Message
                Toast.makeText(
                       getBaseContext(),
                       selectedSeries + " on "  + strDate + " : " + amount ,
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);
}
```

Using the above code I am able to generated following view
[image]

I am now stuck on the customizing the view. How can I remove the black background around the chart. And how can I increase the text size of legends and the xlabel and ylabel as well.
Using the `setLabelsTextSize` will only increase the size of the data in x and y axis (e.g. the date and the temperature value).

Thanks

Updated image:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the legend text size use `multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize()`. To change the outline background color use `multiRenderer.setMarginsColor()`.

As a general note, customizations that involve the entire graph are probably going to be found as part of your `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`. I recommend playing with the different settings and finding what each does.

**ADDITIONAL**

To increase the axes title size use `multiRenderer.setAxesTitleSize()`. As for the axes label colors use `multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor()` and `multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor()`. The axis color can be changed with `multiRenderer.setAxesColor()`.

Again, I encourage you to play with the settings of the renderer. In your IDE, type `multiRenderer.` and all available methods will be shown. Scroll through those and you can probably find what you are looking. Most of the methods have clear descriptive names.

Comment: Thanks it worked but not fully what I wanted to. If you see my question I have added one image. Now I have 2 question `1. How can I increase text size inside the red circle.  2. How can I change the color of the axis value and line i.e in black circle.`

Answer (score 2):

```
Change the color and font size use these code 

XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
            incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(15);
            incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Question vs Time Chart");
            multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
            multiRenderer.setXTitle("Questions");
            multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
            multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
            multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.RED);
            multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.RED);
            multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
            multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
            multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
            double[] set_pan=new double[]{-1.0,Double.MAX_VALUE,0.0,Double.MAX_VALUE+2};
            multiRenderer.setPanLimits(set_pan);
            multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
            multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
            multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(18);
            multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
            multiRenderer.setTextTypeface("Arial", Typeface.BOLD);
            multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
```